# Multiply rows in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

**Table1** has the following 2 columns and 4 rows:

```
Entity Number
------ ------
Car    4
Shop   1
Apple  3
Pear   1
```

I'd like to have one set based SQL query, which produces the below desired results. Basically duplicating the Entities by the Number of times in the Number column.

I could only do it by loop through the rows one by one, which is not really elegant, neither set based.

Desired result:

```
Entity
------
Car   
Car   
Car   
Car   
Shop  
Apple 
Apple 
Apple 
Pear
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select t1.entity, t1.number
      from table1 t1
      union all
      select cte.entity, cte.number - 1
      from cte
      where cte.number > 0
     )
select entity
from cte;
```

Note:  Using the default settings, this is limited to 100 rows per entity.  You can use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to get around this.

You can also solve this with a numbers table, but such a problem is a good introduction to recursive CTEs.

Comment: 1st solution, works perfect, marking as answer ... myself need to dive into recursive queries

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = 1,
        Entity,
        Number
        FROM YourTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SeqNo = SeqNo+1,
        Entity,
        Number
        FROM CTE
            WHERE SeqNo < Number
)
SELECT
    Entity
    FROM CTE
        ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-recursion solution, will be using a fixed sequence number, then join the table based on this number like this:

```
WITH numbers
AS
(
  SELECT n
  FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9), (10)) AS numbers(n)
)
SELECT t.Entity
FROM Table1 AS t
INNER JOIN numbers as n ON t.number >= n.n;
```

This will support up to 10 times duplication, you can add extra numbers to support extra duplication times.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81616/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use spt_values as source for numbers table

```
select EntityList.* 
from EntityList
, (
select number as n from master..spt_values WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and (select max(number) from EntityList)
) t
where n <= number
order by entity
```

[image]

Comment: interesting idea of spt_values, never used that, +1 for the tip, thank you